# If $f:B_2 (0) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic such that $f(\mathbb{S}^1)\subset B_r(z_0)$ then $f(\mathbb{B}^2)\subset B_r(z_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Can you help me with the following please:

> If $f:B_2 (0) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic such that $f(\mathbb{S}^1)\subset B_r(z_0)$ then $f(\mathbb{B}^2)\subset B_r(z_0)$

Where:

$B_r(z_{0})=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-z_0|<r \}$

$\mathbb{B}^2=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|< 1 \}$

$\mathbb{S}^1=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|= 1 \}$

I don't have a lot of resources to do the proof (I've seen few complex analysis theorems) but we saw Cauchy's theorem and it mentioned the following:

"The values of a function within a disk are determined by its boundary"

So, what I think is that this problem is a consequence of the Cauchy integral formula, but I don't know how to express that this result follows from this.

Comment: It's a consequence of the Cauchy integral formula. More precisely, it follows from the maximum principle which can be proved by the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: Thanks, in that case I have a question, how can I relate the rules in this case that I don't know the function and I don't know much about it?

Comment: You don't need to know more. Apply the maximum principle to $g(z) = f(z) - z_0$.

Comment: Oh sure, I see !!  Thank you